# Google Fonts rendering badly in IE and Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, google-webfonts

I'm using Google's Lato font for headings on a website. In most browsers they render beautifully.

In Edge and IE they render perfectly for approximately one second when the page loads - and then suddenly go all squat. It's still Lato, just distorted in height and width - and looks a little pixellated.

It sounds a bit like font-display's "block" and "swap" periods, but not quite.

Given that it renders perfectly for the first second, I assume there's something in Microsoft's browsers that's being applied to it... Does anybody know what's happening, and how I can override it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you embedding your fonts like this? `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have created a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/s2t7Lqkj/), it works well on my side. The result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R69i.png).

Comment: Thanks - I've answered with the solution below. Ultimately a typo in my embed link was to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Ultimately what I was doing wrong was setting font-weight:bold - (which works for some Google fonts fine). But Lato needed:

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

and font-weight:700. Which I tried at one point but made a typo. Looking much better now.